# Debian 10でmake buildをしたら、ErrorやWARNINGがたくさん出てきました。

Tags: javascript, linux, debian

夜分遅くに失礼いたします。お世話になります。

ActivityWatchというManicTimeのようなOSSをインストールしようとしておりますが、`make build`コマンドを実行しますと、「73箇所の脆弱性が見つかりました」と英語で出てきました。

そして、`WARNING Compiled with 14 warnings`と途中で出てきました。
そのうち一例を抽出致しまして質問させていただきます。
下記のbashのコマンドの結果の矢印(#↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓)の下のほうエラーはどのようにして解決すればいいのでしょうか？

お手数をおかけしますが、お手隙でご教授願ます。

```sh
(省略)
added 2294 packages from 1206 contributors and audited 949135 packages in 64.607s
found 73 vulnerabilities (63 low, 2 moderate, 6 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npm run build

> aw-webui@1.0.0 build /home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui
> vue-cli-service build


⠙  Building for production...Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
⠧  Building for production...

 WARNING  Compiled with 14 warnings                                                                                                      12:01:18 AM

#↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'drawLegend' was used before it was defined (@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define) at src/visualizations/sunburst-clock.js:52:3:
  50 |     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');
  51 | 
> 52 |   drawLegend(el);
     |   ^
  53 | 
  54 |   partition = d3.partition().size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius]);
  55 |
```

追記
vue.config.jsに下記のように記述しましたら、エラーが長々と赤文字で出てきました…。

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false
}

module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      template: './src/index.html',
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        PRODUCTION: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: 'static' }]),
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 27180,
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
      openAnalyzer: false,
      analyzerPort: 11000,
    },
  },
};
```

エラーの内容です。

```sh
ebui/node_modules/jest-message-util', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/jest-message-util', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/jest-message-util'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/errno', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/errno', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/errno'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-google-analytics', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-google-analytics', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-google-analytics'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-functional-data-merge', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-functional-data-merge', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-functional-data-merge'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/xml-name-validator', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/xml-name-validator', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/xml-name-validator'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/is-path-cwd', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-path-cwd', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-path-cwd'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/define-property', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/define-property', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/define-property'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/escodegen', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/escodegen', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/escodegen'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/is-symbol', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-symbol', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-symbol'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/defaults', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/defaults', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/defaults'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/aws-sign2', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/aws-sign2', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/aws-sign2'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/browserify-zlib', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/browserify-zlib', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/browserify-zlib'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-parser', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-parser', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-parser'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/resolve', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/resolve', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/resolve'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/sha.js', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/sha.js', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/sha.js'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/string.prototype.padstart', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/string.prototype.padstart', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/string.prototype.padstart'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/regenerate', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/regenerate', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/regenerate'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pirates', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pirates', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pirates'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-load', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-load', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pug-load'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/component-emitter', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/component-emitter', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/component-emitter'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/condense-newlines', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/condense-newlines', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/condense-newlines'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/brace-expansion', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/brace-expansion', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/brace-expansion'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/portal-vue', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/portal-vue', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/portal-vue'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/execa', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/execa', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/execa'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pn', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pn', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pn'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/commander', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/commander', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/commander'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/is-wsl', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-wsl', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/is-wsl'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/unset-value', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/unset-value', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/unset-value'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pbkdf2', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pbkdf2', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pbkdf2'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/pify', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pify', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/pify'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-streams', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-streams', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/workbox-streams'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/file-loader', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/file-loader', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/file-loader'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/jest-watcher', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/jest-watcher', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/jest-watcher'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/ws', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/ws', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/ws'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/acorn-globals', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/acorn-globals', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/acorn-globals'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/posix-character-classes', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/posix-character-classes', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/posix-character-classes'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/trim-right', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/trim-right', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/trim-right'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/dns-packet', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/dns-packet', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/dns-packet'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/repeat-element', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/repeat-element', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/repeat-element'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-axis', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-axis', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-axis'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/ecc-jsbn', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/ecc-jsbn', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/ecc-jsbn'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/renderkid', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/renderkid', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/renderkid'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/strict-uri-encode', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/strict-uri-encode', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/strict-uri-encode'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/npm-run-path', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/npm-run-path', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/npm-run-path'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/imports-loader', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/imports-loader', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/imports-loader'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/p-locate', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/p-locate', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/p-locate'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/@webassemblyjs', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/@webassemblyjs', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/@webassemblyjs'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-hot-reload-api', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-hot-reload-api', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/vue-hot-reload-api'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/stream-shift', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/stream-shift', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/stream-shift'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-time', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-time', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/node_modules/d3-time'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/.git', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.git', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/jest.config.js', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/jest.config.js', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/.travis.yml', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.travis.yml', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/dist', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/dist', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/dist'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/.prettierrc.yml', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.prettierrc.yml', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/.github', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.github', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.github'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/.editorconfig', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/.editorconfig', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/src', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/src', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/src'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/static', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/static', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/static'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/LICENSE.txt', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/LICENSE.txt', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/babel.config.js', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/babel.config.js', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/tsconfig.json', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/tsconfig.json', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/package.json', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/package.json', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/Makefile', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-webui/Makefile', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/README.md', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/README.md', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/tests', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/tests', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/tests'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/Pipfile.lock', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/Pipfile.lock', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw-server.spec', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw-server.spec', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/requirements.txt', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/requirements.txt', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/Pipfile', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/Pipfile', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/.git', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/.git', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/aw_server', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw_server', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/aw_server'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/scripts', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/scripts', "[Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/scripts'"), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/.travis.yml', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/.travis.yml', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/LICENSE.txt', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/LICENSE.txt', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/requirements-dev.txt', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/requirements-dev.txt', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/MANIFEST.in', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/MANIFEST.in', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/build.sh', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/build.sh', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'), ('/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-server/Makefile', '/tmp/pip-req-build-twizmmlr/Makefile', '[Errno 28] No space left on device')]
```

[ActivityWatchのインストールの公式ドキュメント](https://activitywatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-from-source.html#)

※[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/227445?modal=q-comp)にもマルチポストさせていただきますのでご容赦願います。

Comment: これは ESlint による lint check ですので、(メッセージにもある通り)実際にはコンパイルエラーではなくワーニングになります(エラーだと言っているのは ESlint で、ESlint のチェックはかなり厳格です)。Lint check を行わない場合は [How to disable ESLint in vue-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273373) の通りにすれば良いでしょう。対象のファイルは `activitywatch/aw-server/aw-webui/vue.config.js` になります。

Comment: > metropolis様　ありがとうございます。
`module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: './src/main.js',
      template: './src/index.html',
    },
  },
`
のどちらに`lintOnSave: false`を記述すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: > metropolis様　追記をさせていただきました。

Comment: 最初で良いと思います。`module.exports = { lintOnSave: false, pages: { ...`

Comment: > metropolis様 ありがとうございました。今度は別のエラーが出ましたので、別のページで質問を投稿させていただきます。